# Variance of a Gaussian Random Variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Show Variance of a Gaussian random variable $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and I know $\mathbb{E}(X)^2 = \mu^2$.

So I need
$\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ = 
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}dx$.
The final result should be $\sigma^2 + \mu^2$, but I cannot see the integration trick used to do this.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{E}(X)^2 = \mu^2$ (not $\mu$) and that it should read $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}$ instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If you want to calculate it using an integral expression, it is actually easier to calculate the variance directly, i.e.

$$\text{var}(X) = \mathbb{E}((X-\mu)^2) = \int (x-\mu)^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp \left(- \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \, dx.$$

To this end, write

$$\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{2\pi}} \int(x-\mu) \cdot \left[ \frac{(x-\mu)}{\sigma^2} \exp \left(- \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \right] \, dx$$

and use integration by parts.

Comment: Could you give a bit more insight on why you divided by $\sigma^2$? I have seen its a common trick but don't understand the reasoning behind the trick.

Comment: @Mid Well, we want to use integration by parts, right? Since $$\frac{d}{dx} \exp \left( - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) = \frac{(x-\mu)}{\sigma^2} \exp \left( - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)$$ the factor $\sigma^2$ is convenient.